# How to do direct effect to change font color?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet, actionsheetpicker

I allow when user select font color from ActionSheetPicker then font color of text change when color is change.I use the third party library https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0
How can i do it ?
I have to change in third party library or make customization of ActionSheetPicker.

Is there any value change event to make this functionality?

Here is the image actually that i want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2bz0.png

Answer (score 0):

In the done block of `showPickerWithTitle:rows:initialSelection:doneBlock:cancelBlock:origin`
you can know which index or value was picked and change the colour of your text accordingly.

```
[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a Color"
                                        rows:colors
                            initialSelection:0
                                   doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {                                       
                                      yourLabel.textColor = ...
                                    }
                                 cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                      NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
                                    }
                                      origin:sender];
```

Comment: it will set color when i press done button of actionsheetpicker not do effect like value change event

Comment: then you will have to override his 
- pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: method and send the right message to your view controller either by delegation or blocks

Answer (score 0):

First in ur project navigate to Picker folder and open `ActionSheetStringPicker.m`
then add below code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

     NSString *str_lbl = (self.data)[(NSUInteger) row];

    //NSLog(@"////////%@",obj);

    UILabel *label = (UILabel*) view;
    if (label == nil)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }

    [label setText:str_lbl];

    // This part just colorizes everything, since you asked about that.

    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    if ([str_lbl isEqualToString:@"Red"])
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else if([str_lbl isEqualToString:@"Green"])
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
    else if([str_lbl isEqualToString:@"Blue"])
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
    else if([str_lbl isEqualToString:@"Orange"])
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    }
    else
    {

    }

   // [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    CGSize rowSize = [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component];
    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, rowSize.width, rowSize.height);
    [label setFrame:labelRect];

    return label;
}
```

Comment: method is called or not?

Comment: method is called and it's add label text to actionsheetpicker and i don't want that so,please refer my question 2nd time.